# How to randomize the order of the variable? I mean I want to randomize the order of the variables to be input

Tags: string, variables, random, input, integer

```
ask2 = input(str("So, my friend, how's the life goin' on?"))
ask3 = input(str("Did you code today? Do you even code?"))
```

So, I just want to get these two questions, in randomized order. And yea, I tried importing random module and even tried to use the *random.shuffle* & *random.choice* but it told me that it is only for integers.
Any help, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
random_integer = random.randint(1, 2)

if random_integer == 1:
    ask2 = input(str("So, my friend, how's the life goin' on?"))
elif random_integer == 2:
    ask3 = input(str("Did you code today? Do you even code?"))
```